# Delete all rows with criterias

Tags: excel, vba

I need VBA code that will delete all rows with column A equal to "XXX" if column B is equal to "YYY".

Example: I have a spreadsheet that looks like this: column A has multiple rows with the same value but the value in column B is different for every row. I want to delete all the records with the same value in column A if column B has a specific value.

Comment: How many rows do you have? Filter then sort?

Comment: So you want to delete the rows if they match?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? This is not a please code this for me site. This site is for fixing broken code. As this question is now it is off topic on here.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that would be very easy to create using the Macro record feature of excel and then modify the code to fit the specifics you are needing.

Comment: Yes I have tried. I have the rows deleting if a certain criteria is met. I am creating a spreadsheet for users that are not very computer literate. By pressing a command button I want them the macro to be able to delete rows looking at 2 specific columns. Value in column A repeats multiple times with a different value in column B. For example Row 1 has in Column A: 100234 and in Column B: AD&D. Row 2 has the same value in column A but different in column B. I need the code to lookup specific value in column B, identify the value in A and delete all rows with the same value in A.

Comment: This should just be an easy step by step approach. 1. Filter B by that value (you have not said how you are determining the value for B), 2. Look at value in any row of A if they are the same and save it to a variable, 3. Unfilter all, 4. Filter A by the variable, 5. Delete lines.